# How to output HTML from array in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Sorry if the subject is a bit strange. But I didn't know what else to name it.

I would like to style this peace of code to fit with the style of my website.

```
<?php 
  global $post;
  $opties = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Items', array("fields" => "names"));
  if (count($opties) > 0) {
      echo implode(', ', $opties);  
  }
?>
```

Right now it echo's

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc...
```

I would like to have it echo the following:

```
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Item 1<br>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Item 2<br>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Item 3<br>
```

How to I get this code to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try combining `foreach` and `echo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine HTML easily by using the alternative syntax for `foreach`.

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $opties = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Items', array("fields" => "names"));
    foreach ($opties as $o): ?>
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $o ?></i>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `foreach` loop to loop through all record and display it.

```
<?php 
  global $post;
  $opties = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Items', array("fields" => "names"));
  foreach($opties as $opt) {
     echo '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.$opt.'<br>';
  }   
?>
```

Comment: count is not required, coz foreach do nothing on empty resource ;)